# iOS facebook login ask for permission every time

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using FBLoginView in my iOS app. I do everything like in [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial) tutorial. Everything works great except one thing. When I logout and then login again via facebook it opens view with ask for grant permission to app with information I grant permission already. How can I skip this view after grant permission first time?

Comment: could you provide the code for login out ?, I think you clear and close the session so when you login again will ask for permissions.

Comment: I do it like this: [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; outside login view and in login view I just click in logout button from Facebook SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to log out :

Closes the local in-memory session object, but does not clear the persisted token cache.

```
[[FBSession activeSession] close];
```

and

Closes the in-memory session, and clears any persisted cache related to the session.

```
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

In your case, I think that using the first option rather than the second will keep your token, and you won't need to ask permission again.